# Pandas dataframe - Rearranging row index values into column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am trying to get from the following dataframe:

```
          DAY    Col1    ColA    ColB    ColC
    ID    
    ABC   Mon    A        123
    DEF   Mon    A        456
    GHI   Mon    A        789
    ABC   Tue    A                123
    DEF   Tue    A                456
    GHI   Tue    A                789
    ABC   Wed    A                        123
    DEF   Wed    A                        456
    GHI   Wed    A                        789
```

into:

```
    ID    Mon    Tue    Wed
    ABC   123    123    123
    DEF   456    456    456
    GHI   789    789    789
```

So the idea would be to remove the empty cells, and reclassify the columns into unique Days followed by the ID's corresponding value in that Day.

Appreciate any help I get, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = (df.drop('Col1', 1)
        .set_index(['ID','DAY'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .unstack())
print (df)
DAY    Mon    Tue    Wed
ID                      
ABC  123.0  123.0  123.0
DEF  456.0  456.0  456.0
GHI  789.0  789.0  789.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. Remove unnecessary column `Col1` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
2. Create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove `NaN`s and columns names to `MultiIndex`
4. Remove 2 level of `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
5. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

EDIT:

```
df = (df.drop('Col1', 1)
        .set_index('DAY', append=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .unstack()
        )
print (df)
DAY    Mon    Tue    Wed
ID                      
ABC  123.0  123.0  123.0
DEF  456.0  456.0  456.0
GHI  789.0  789.0  789.0
```

EDIT1: Add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.drop('Col1', 1)
        .set_index('DAY', append=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .unstack()
        .reindex(columns=['Wed','Tue','Mon'])
        )
print (df)
DAY    Wed    Tue    Mon
ID                      
ABC  123.0  123.0  123.0
DEF  456.0  456.0  456.0
GHI  789.0  789.0  789.0
```

Comment: Really interesting +1

Comment: @RaoSahab - Thank you.

Comment: Just realised the dataframe I have at the start is a MultiIndex - how can i remedy that please?

Comment: @Singapore123 - What is `print (df.index.nlevels)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Not too sure either. I made some edits to the original table in the question. Table I'm starting with has a multiindex, vs just single before

Comment: @Singapore123 - `print (df.index.nlevels)` does not work? It means how many columns are used for `MultiIndex` ? 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @jezrael ok i got your question now - it returns 1

Comment: strange because there's an empty row along 'ID'. It's not allowing me to execute your above suggested solution too

Comment: Yes so there is an KeyError: 'ID'. I guess it's because the ID header is inn a row below the other column headers?

Comment: @Singapore123 - Becasue in is not column, but index. I edit answer, can you check it?

Comment: Can I add a new question pls: If i want the dates to be in descending order (Wed to Mon), how can i do it?

Comment: Would there be a more generic way of arranging? Actually the actual data in Day are made up of dates (Eg 2017-1-31, 2017-2-28, 2017,3-31)

Comment: @Singapore123 - Sure, in final `df` is `print (df.columns)` `datetimeindex` or not?

Comment: @Singapore123 - super, then change `.reindex(columns=['Wed','Tue','Mon'])` to `.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)`

Comment: Great super helpful! the sorting works but it now appears as a date time (2017-12-31 00:00:00). How should i remove the timestamp portion?

Comment: @Singapore123 - It means there are some times in each one datetime. Do you need remove all times?

Comment: Yes i want to remove all the times, just the dates will be good enough

Comment: OK, so first step of solution is `df['DAY'] = df['DAY'].dt.floor('d')` or slowier `df['DAY'] = df['DAY'].dt.date`